# How does the Douay Rheims Bible(DRB) translate burnt offering עֹלָ֥ה as Holocaust in Numbers 28:3?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, numbers, nasb, douay-rheims

3 These are the sacrifices which you shall offer: Two lambs of a year old without blemish every day for the perpetual ***holocaust***

In other versions it is translated as burnt offering:

KJV

3 And thou shalt say unto them, This is the offering made by fire which ye shall offer unto the Lord; two lambs of the first year without spot day by day, for a continual ***burnt offering***.

NASB

3 You shall say to them, ‘This is the offering by fire which you shall offer to the Lord: two male lambs one year old without defect as a continual ***burnt offering*** every day

So how does the DRB translate this term?

Answer (score 3):

The original meaning of the word in the 16th century:

> The word Holocaust is derived from the Greek holokauston, a translation of the Hebrew word ʿolah, meaning a burnt sacrifice offered whole to God. This word was chosen, and gained wide usage, because, in the ultimate manifestation of the Nazi killing program—the extermination camps—the bodies of the victims were consumed whole in crematoria or open fires.

https://www.britannica.com/story/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-holocaust

Comment: Brave but completely correct answer.  Well done.  In the very modern era, no one would ever use this word in this context again because it has acquired a very specialised and technical meaning somewhat adrift from its original meaning that your correctly list.

Comment: The link gives the explanation of how we got the modern meaning.